# Area of the region enclosed by three curves

Tags: calculus, area, curves

find the area between:

$$\begin{array}{}
y=4\\
y=2\sqrt{x}\\
y=3-x
\end{array}$$

I have found the intersection points between the curves to find the interval but even while doing it with respect to x or to y, my answer is always wrong. please help

Comment: You should post your answer so that we can point out the mistake, if any.

Comment: If you show us your work then we might be able to tell you where you’re going wrong.

Comment: the problem is not so clear have you made a picture?

Comment: It looks straight forward to me.  Exactly WHAT did you do?  What answer did you get?  What answer do you think you should have gotten?

Comment: help yourself with http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7B4%2C2%E2%88%9Ax%2C3-x%7D%2C+-1.1%3Cx%3C4.2

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

1. Take a look at this picture

[image]

2. You should compute

$$\text{Area}=\color{blue}{\text{Blue}}+\color{green}{\text{Green}}=\int_{-1}^{1} (4-(3-x)) dx + \int_{1}^{4} (4-2\sqrt x) dx$$

3. The final answer is $\frac{14}{3}$

Comment: +1 for plots. Answer with pictures beats answers without pictures all day every day.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Draw a diagram indicating the required area bounded by $y=4$, $y=2\sqrt x$ & $y=3-x$. Divide the bounded region into two smaller regions, then one should get area bounded $$=\frac{1}{2}(2\times 2)+\left(3\times 4-\int_{1}^{4}2\sqrt x\ dx\right) $$